# Which Ubuntu 12.10 on Mac

Tags: installation, 64-bit, mac

I'm about to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my Mac but I'm not sure which .iso I should download. I have a Macbook Pro intel core i5 64 bit. What of the following will suit best on my system?

```
PC (Intel x86) desktop image
64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop image
```

I'm not sure because I hve a 64 bit mac as the second tells but it is an x86 too. I have also Windows 7 installed and I'd like a triple boot. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a 64-bit compatible computer, I can see no reason to stick with 32-bit OS. 32-bit Ubuntu would be (a little bit more than) slightly slower on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: But I have an x86 processor not an AMD

Comment: I guess you're confused with the **amd64** iso. An amd64 ubuntu iso means a 64 bit iso which is suitable for both Intel and Amd 64 bit processors. 64 bit Ubuntu would seamlessly run on your computer.

Comment: Thanks, That was my doubt... I installed the 64 bit version and it works perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome :) enjoy the best OS of all :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a 64-bit system is capable to run on all processors, but for Ubuntu I would recommend to use the 32-bit OS, because it is more stable and better supported.

Comment: You're completely wrong.

Comment: A 64-bit system requires a 64-bit processor. It can run both 32-bit and 64 bit programs(but only 64-bit drivers). A 32-bit version will run on any CPU but will not be able to run 64-bit programs.